# Не корректно работает root в nginx

Tags: nginx, root, alias, location

есть конфигурация nginx

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  client.test.domain;

    charset utf-8;

    root /var/www/_test.domain/client/;
    index  index.php index.html;

    client_max_body_size 0;

    location / {
        #root /var/www/_test.domain/client/;
    }
    location /html {
        #root /var/www/_test.domain/;
        alias /var/www/_test.domain/html;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php-www.sock;
        #fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1.:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 64k;
        fastcgi_buffers 4 64k;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param HTTPS on;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/_test.domain/client$fastcgi_script_name;
        #fastcgi_param PHP_ADMIN_VALUE "open_basedir=/var/www:/tmp:/var/lib/sessions:/var/www/tmp:/var/www/log";
        #include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    }


    location ~* /(images|cache|media|logs|tmp)/.*\.(php|pl|py|jsp|asp|sh|cgi)$ {
        return 403;
        error_page 403 /403_error.html;
    }

    # caching of files
    location ~* \.(ico|pdf|flv)$ {
        expires 1y;
    }
    location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|swf|xml|txt)$ {
        expires 14d;
    }

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}
```

При такой конфигурации скрипты работают, при запросе `client.test.domain/html/css/style.css` выдает `404 Not found`

в логе nginx видно что файл ищет
`"/var/www/_test.domain/client/html/css/style.css"`

если же сделать так

```
    #root /var/www/_test.domain/client/;
    index  index.php index.html;

    client_max_body_size 0;

    location / {
        root /var/www/_test.domain/client/;
    }
    location /html {
        #root /var/www/_test.domain/;
        alias /var/www/_test.domain/html;
    }
```

то он пытается найти файл в `"/etc/nginx/html/html/css/style.css"`

замена на `root` тоже игнорируется.

я уже сломал весь мозг. Потому как в документации сказано что `root` и `alias` в `location` должно работать.

но вот у меня не работает.(((

Comment: `location /html/ { root /var/www/_test.domain; }`

Comment: К сожалению тоже нет.
в данном случае они пытается найти файл по "/var/www/_test.domain/client/html/css/style.css"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

в nginx ответили

`location ^~ /html { }`